# How to dump a Python dictionary to JSON when keys are non-trivial objects?

Tags: python, json

```
import datetime, json
x = {'alpha': {datetime.date.today(): 'abcde'}}
print json.dumps(x)
```

The above code fails with a `TypeError` since keys of JSON objects need to be strings. The `json.dumps` function has a parameter called default that is called when the *value* of a JSON object raises a `TypeError`, but there seems to be no way to do this for the *key*. What is the most elegant way to work around this?

Comment: Would it suffice to convert the `datetime` object to a string using `strftime`? Or are you looking for a generic way for complex objects?

Comment: In this case, converting datetime.date's to strings via the isoformat() method works. However, it has to work on the keys of the dictionary, as well as values.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393059/json-dump-not-calling-default-or-cls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend json.JSONEncoder to create your own encoder which will be able to deal with datetime.datetime objects (or objects of any type you desire) in such a way that a string is created which can be reproduced as a new datetime.datetime instance. I believe it should be as simple as having json.JSONEncoder call repr() on your datetime.datetime instances.

The procedure on how to do so is described in the [json module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder).

The json module checks the type of each value it needs to encode and by default it only knows how to handle dicts, lists, tuples, strs, unicode objects, int, long, float, boolean and none :-)

Also of importance for you might be the skipkeys argument to the JSONEncoder.

---

After reading your comments I have concluded that there is no easy solution to have JSONEncoder encode the keys of dictionaries with a custom function. If you are interested you can look at the source and the methods iterencode() which calls _iterencode() which calls _iterencode_dict() which is where the type error gets raised.

Easiest for you would be to create a new dict with isoformatted keys like this:

```
import datetime, json

D = {datetime.datetime.now(): 'foo',
     datetime.datetime.now(): 'bar'}

new_D = {}

for k,v in D.iteritems():
  new_D[k.isoformat()] = v

json.dumps(new_D)
```

Which returns '{"2010-09-15T23:24:36.169710": "foo", "2010-09-15T23:24:36.169723": "bar"}'. For niceties, wrap it in a function :-)

Comment: That only works for values of the dictionary, not keys. There appears to be no way to override encoding of the keys.

Comment: You are correct, let me find the solution in the source (you can possibly override JSONEncoder.iterencode) as it is not clearly documented.

Comment: Okay, I checked the source and it is not possible to make a JSONEncoder instance encode dict keys with a custom function for a certain type easily. You would be best to create a new dict with the keys. I will update my answer to reflect on this.

Comment: Thanks. I guess no general purpose way will exist. I guess I should go and see whether at some point this can be corrected in the Python SDL as it seems like a useful feature.

Comment: The reason why this is done is because there is no 'fail safe' way to convert an object of any kind to the required string type for a json key. It could call repr() or str() on a object which is not basestring but those are not always implemented/useful and Pythons motto is to not do things implicitly which would include doing this.

Comment: That makes sense. But having the ability to define this behavior would be nice. It already has the default() method you can override. Why not provide a default_key() method?

Comment: Maybe it's time to make a contribution to the Python Standard Library

Comment: I think that this accepted answer should be edited to answer at the begining that IT CAN NOT BE DONE. Right now, it is answering the wrong question and then correcting aftewawards. Also, @ipartola this an old issue in cpython if somebody wants to follow the issue:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/63020

Answer (score 2):

http://jsonpickle.github.io/ might be what you want. When facing a similar issue, I ended up doing:

```
to_save = jsonpickle.encode(THE_THING, unpicklable=False, max_depth=4, make_refs=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do
`x = {'alpha': {datetime.date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'): 'abcde'}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it, you can monkeypatch json.encoder:

```py
from _json import encode_basestring_ascii  # used when ensure_ascii=True (which is the default where you want everything to be ascii)
from _json import encode_basestring  # used in any other case

def _patched_encode_basestring(o):
    """
    Monkey-patching Python's json serializer so it can serialize keys that are not string!
    You can monkey patch the ascii one the same way.
    """
    if isinstance(o, MyClass):
        return my_serialize(o)
    return encode_basestring(o)


json.encoder.encode_basestring = _patched_encode_basestring
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON only accepts the [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) mentioned data types for encoding. As @supakeen mentioned, you can extend the JSONEncoder class in order to encode any values inside a dictionary but no keys! If you want to encode keys, you have to do it on your own.

I used a recursive function in order to encode tuple-keys as strings and recover them later.

Here an example:

```
def _tuple_to_string(obj: Any) -> Any:
"""Serialize tuple-keys to string representation. A tuple wil be obtain a leading '__tuple__' string and decomposed in list representation.

Args:
    obj (Any): Typically a dict, tuple, list, int, or string.

Returns:
    Any: Input object with serialized tuples.
"""
# deep copy object to avoid manipulation during iteration
obj_copy = copy.deepcopy(obj)
# if the object is a dictionary
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    # iterate over every key
    for key in obj:
        # set for later to avoid modification in later iterations when this var does not get overwritten
        serialized_key = None
        # if key is tuple
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            # stringify the key
            serialized_key = f"__tuple__{list(key)}"
            # replace old key with encoded key
            obj_copy[serialized_key] = obj_copy.pop(key)
        # if the key was modified
        if serialized_key is not None:
            # do it again for the next nested dictionary
            obj_copy[serialized_key] = _tuple_to_string(obj[key])
        # else, just do it for the next dictionary
        else:
            obj_copy[key] = _tuple_to_string(obj[key])
return obj_copy
```

This will turn a tuple of the form `("blah", "blub")` to `"__tuple__["blah", "blub"]"` so that you can dump it using `json.dumps()` or `json.dump()`. You can use the leading `"__tuple"__` to detect them during decoding. Therefore, I used this function:

```
def _string_to_tuple(obj: Any) -> Any:
"""Convert serialized tuples back to original representation. Tuples need to have a leading "__tuple__" string.

Args:
    obj (Any): Typically a dict, tuple, list, int, or string.

Returns:
    Any: Input object with recovered tuples.
"""
# deep copy object to avoid manipulation during iteration
obj_copy = copy.deepcopy(obj)
# if the object is a dictionary
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    # iterate over every key
    for key in obj:
        # set for later to avoid modification in later iterations when this var does not get overwritten
        serialized_key = None
        # if key is a serialized tuple starting with the "__tuple__" affix
        if isinstance(key, str) and key.startswith("__tuple__"):
            # decode it so tuple
            serialized_key = tuple(key.split("__tuple__")[1].strip("[]").replace("'", "").split(", "))
            # if key is number in string representation
            if all(entry.isdigit() for entry in serialized_key):
                # convert to integer
                serialized_key = tuple(map(int, serialized_key))
            # replace old key with encoded key
            obj_copy[serialized_key] = obj_copy.pop(key)
        # if the key was modified
        if serialized_key is not None:
            # do it again for the next nested dictionary
            obj_copy[serialized_key] = _string_to_tuple(obj[key])
        # else, just do it for the next dictionary
        else:
            obj_copy[key] = _string_to_tuple(obj[key])
# if another instance was found
elif isinstance(obj, list):
    for item in obj:
        _string_to_tuple(item)
return obj_copy
```

Insert you custom logic for en-/decoding your instance by changing the

```
if isinstance(key, tuple):
    # stringify the key
    serialized_key = f"__tuple__{list(key)}"
```

in the `_tuple_to_string` function or the corresponding code block from the `_string_to_tuple` function, respectively:

```
if isinstance(key, str) and key.startswith("__tuple__"):
    # decode it so tuple
    serialized_key = tuple(key.split("__tuple__")[1].strip("[]").replace("'", "").split(", "))
    # if key is number in string representation
    if all(entry.isdigit() for entry in serialized_key):
        # convert to integer
        serialized_key = tuple(map(int, serialized_key))
```

Then, you can use it as usual:

```
>>> dct = {("L1", "L1"): {("L2", "L2"): "foo"}}
>>> json.dumps(_tuple_to_string(dct))
... {"__tuple__['L1', 'L2']": {"__tuple__['L2', 'L2']": "foo"}}
```

Hope, I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

This something that CAN NOT BE DONE. That is, the default function in json or alternatively extending the `JsonEncoder` approach will not work. See this issue:

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/63020

The reason being that the developers thing that supporting anything other than strings for serialization should be disavowed.

See also:
[json.dump not calling default or cls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393059/json-dump-not-calling-default-or-cls)