# json.dump not calling default or cls

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, datetime

Trying to serialize a dict containing datetime objects as keys to json. A few other answers have suggested using the `json.dump` parameters `default` or `cls` however, neither of these methods appear to be even called. See MWEs below. What am I missing?

**Using `Default`**

```
from datetime import datetime
import json

def default(obj):
    print("Default Called")
    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        return obj.isoformat()

test = {datetime(1970, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0): 10}

with open("output.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump(test, fo, default=default)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    json.dump(test, fo, default=default)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 376, in _iterencode_dict
    raise TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not datetime
```

**Using `cls`**

```
from datetime import datetime
import json

class DateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        print("Default called")
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
            return obj.isoformat()

        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

test = {datetime(1970, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0): 10}

with open("output.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump(test, fo, cls=DateEncoder)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    json.dump(test, fo, cls=DateEncoder)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 376, in _iterencode_dict
    raise TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not datetime
```

Comment: datetime objects are immutable https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TLDR: `.default` is only called for `dict` values, not keys.

To elaborate on Abhishek Kumars answer; after reviewing the `json.JSONEncoder` source, `.default` is only ever called on `dict` values that are not serializable, never keys. Keys must be one of `str`, `int`, `float`, `bool` or `None`.

To use `datetime` objects as keys, `.iterencode` must be overwritten to use recursive pre-processor method to convert `datetime` to `str`:

```
test = {
        "key_1": "Value_1",
        "key_2": 10,
        "key_3": ["list_" + str(i) for i in range(5)],
        "key_4": {"nestkey_" + str(i) : "nestvalue_" + str(i) for i in range(5) },
        "key_5": datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0): "datetime_key"
}

class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def _preprocess_date(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime, datetime.timedelta)):
            return str(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, dict):
            return {self._preprocess_date(k): self._preprocess_date(v) for k,v in obj.items()}
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            return [self._preprocess_date(i) for i in obj]
        return obj

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime, datetime.timedelta)):
            return str(obj)
        return super().default(obj)

    def iterencode(self, obj):
        return super().iterencode(self._preprocess_date(obj))

with open('output.json', 'w') as fo:
    json.dump(test, fo, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
```

This is obviously an expensive operation for larger dictionaries so some caution should be exercised. Also, would be nice for `json.JSONEncoder` to be updated to use default on keys as well as values - issue created at : https://bugs.python.org/issue41569

Comment: It seems iterencode need a _one_shot parameter:
`def iterencode(self, obj,_one_shot):`

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
class DatesToStrings(json.JSONEncoder):
    def _encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            def transform_date(o):
                return self._encode(o.isoformat() if isinstance(o, datetime) else o)
            return {transform_date(k): transform_date(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
        else:
            return obj

    def encode(self, obj):
        return super(DatesToStrings, self).encode(self._encode(obj))
```

```
with open("output.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump( json.dumps( test, cls=DatesToStrings), fo, cls=DatesToStrings)
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek but unfortunately its still returning `TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Did you try this :: `with open("out.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump( json.dumps( test, cls=DatesToStrings), fo)`

Comment: Yes, I've tried both versions. Could you tell me how you defined `test` please?

Comment: i just copied your test :`test = {datetime(1970, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0): 10}`

Comment: Spotted a type on my side. Yes, this works. Thanks. Any idea why my original post is not working?

Comment: as it says in the error .. the key cannot be datetime ,...

Comment: I don't think that's the case; both `default` and `cls` should be called in the event of a unsupported datatype and as you can see from the add printed statements I added there, the methods are not being called